# NFS share hide directories and folders for users without permission

Tags: nfs, freenas

I have a simple FreeNAS server that id just like to share with some people but I'd like to hide directories from users that they don't have permissions for but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I can edit the permissions on files and folders that if they try to access them they get a read only or permission denied but I'd like to physically hide the file or folder contents from them so that they couldn't even see them in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way of doing this with a NFS share (I think SMB + ACL supports it). You have to restrict read permission on the parent folder to achieve what you want.

Assuming that renaming the folders to start with a `.` is not enough, because a `ls -a` will still list them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're okay to go NFSv4 only, then you can disable network access to `mountd` via `/etc/hosts.deny`:

```
mountd: ALL
```

`showmount` will not list any shares then, and the other people/clients need to need the exact path to the shared directory.